# alert event working but my javascript function for on click change color is not working

Tags: javascript, php, html

I created a javascript function called toggleColor in the head tag. With this I wanted to change the table row color to red when clicked. At the bottom of my main code within my td tag I added on click for my function, but for some reason this is not working. When I hardcode and alert function within the on click for clicking a certain row it opens up an alert, but when I even try to hardcode within my td tag by changing color to red it still didn't work which is quite confusing. I have looked into a few resources for this and I have done it exactly the way they have set up, but still no luck. Would really appreciate some help.

Main Code:

```
<?php print( '<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>') ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>User selection page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="gameViewStyleSheet.css" type="text/css" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
      function toggleColor(this)
      {
        this.style.backgroundColor='red';
      }
    </script>
  </head>


    <?php
        /*
        Version 1.1: Instead of printing the teams in different cells we are going to print the 
        games in one row and we select the game itself to see if an upset will occur. This version 
        provides this functionality with a table for each conference. Currently Data is still hard-
        coded and each table prints the west conference data. We will pull data from the DB once it 
        is set up. That will be provided in the next version.
        */  

        require_once('Conference.php'); 

        for ($j = 0; $j<4; $j++)
        {       
            $loadGameClass = new Conference();
            $loadGameClass->loadTeams(array("(1)Gonzaga vs (16)Southern U", "(8)Pittsburgh vs (9)Wichita St", "(5)Wisconsin vs (12)Ole Miss", "(4)Kansas st vs (13)Boise St", "(6)Arizona vs (11)Belmont", "(3)New Mexico vs (14) Harvard", "(7)Notre Dame vs (10)Iowa St", "(2)Ohio St vs (15) Iona"));
            $teams = $loadGameClass->getTeams();

            echo '<table border="1" align="center">';

            switch ($j) {
                case 0:
                    echo "Midwest";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    echo "West";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    echo "South";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    echo "East";
                    break;  
                }

            //echo '<div class = ".table_entries">';

            for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) 
            {
                $games = $teams[$i];
                echo '<tr><td onclick="toggleColor(this)">'.$games.'</td><tr>';
            }

            echo '</table>';
            echo "<br>" . "<br>";

            //echo '</div>';

        }
    ?>

    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Conference:

```
<?php

class Conference
{
    protected $teams;

    function loadTeams($teams)
    {
        $this->teams = $teams;
    }

    function getTeams()
    {
        return $this->teams;
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have a parameter named `this`, since `this` has a special meaning in Javascript.

Change the following function:

```
function toggleColor(this)
{
    this.style.backgroundColor='red';
}
```

To:

```
function toggleColor(el)
{
    el.style.backgroundColor='red';
}
```

**Update**:

```
function toggleColor(el)
{
    var s = el.style;
    s.backgroundColor = (s.backgroundColor === 'red' ? 'white' : 'red');
}
```

Comment: This ended up working thank you for the help! Unfortunately when using the term 'red' it would not fix it so I had to put "#FF0000" this ended up working.

Comment: @user2522055 Strange, `red` should work as well. It works for me in Chrome at least. Also note that `#F00` is a shorthand for `#FF0000`

Comment: After making some changes it seemed to work. I don't know if it was my localhost using MAMP that constantly keeps messing up or it was actually the code. Now I actually wanted to change that color back to the original color white after the on click again. I tried using if (this.style.backgroundColor='white'){
this.style.backgroundColor='red';
}
else{
this.style.backgroundColor='white';
}
this did not end up working

Comment: Thank you worked wonderfully! Weird thing that happened was that my CSS changed all the tables for some reason after adding that line of code.

Answer (score 1):

this is a reserved word

onclick="toggleColor.call(this)";

```
function toggleColor()
{
this.style.backgroundColor='red';
}
```